# Get today users registered per hour

Tags: php, php-carbon, laravel-5.6

```
public static function todayUsersPerHour() {
    $today = Carbon::today();
    $users = array();
    $hours = array();

        $a = 1;
    for($h = 0; $h < 24; $h++){
        $today->addHour($a);
        $sub = $today;
        array_push($hours, $today.' - '.$sub->subHour());
        $user = User::where([
            ['created_at', '<=', $today],
            ['created_at','>',$sub]
        ])->count();
        array_push($users, $user);
    }
    return $hours;
}
```

I have this static method that doesn't work as I wanted to.

When I run this in laravel tinker I get:

```
[
     "2018-06-02 01:00:00 - 2018-06-02 00:00:00",
     "2018-06-02 01:00:00 - 2018-06-02 00:00:00",
     "2018-06-02 01:00:00 - 2018-06-02 00:00:00",
     "2018-06-02 01:00:00 - 2018-06-02 00:00:00",
     "2018-06-02 01:00:00 - 2018-06-02 00:00:00",
     "2018-06-02 01:00:00 - 2018-06-02 00:00:00",
     "2018-06-02 01:00:00 - 2018-06-02 00:00:00",
     "2018-06-02 01:00:00 - 2018-06-02 00:00:00",
     "2018-06-02 01:00:00 - 2018-06-02 00:00:00",
     "2018-06-02 01:00:00 - 2018-06-02 00:00:00",
     "2018-06-02 01:00:00 - 2018-06-02 00:00:00",
     "2018-06-02 01:00:00 - 2018-06-02 00:00:00",
     "2018-06-02 01:00:00 - 2018-06-02 00:00:00",
     "2018-06-02 01:00:00 - 2018-06-02 00:00:00",
     "2018-06-02 01:00:00 - 2018-06-02 00:00:00",
     "2018-06-02 01:00:00 - 2018-06-02 00:00:00",
     "2018-06-02 01:00:00 - 2018-06-02 00:00:00",
     "2018-06-02 01:00:00 - 2018-06-02 00:00:00",
     "2018-06-02 01:00:00 - 2018-06-02 00:00:00",
     "2018-06-02 01:00:00 - 2018-06-02 00:00:00",
     "2018-06-02 01:00:00 - 2018-06-02 00:00:00",
     "2018-06-02 01:00:00 - 2018-06-02 00:00:00",
     "2018-06-02 01:00:00 - 2018-06-02 00:00:00",
     "2018-06-02 01:00:00 - 2018-06-02 00:00:00",
   ]
```

When I add `$a++` into the loop I get:

```
[
     "2018-06-02 01:00:00 - 2018-06-02 00:00:00",
     "2018-06-02 02:00:00 - 2018-06-02 01:00:00",
     "2018-06-02 04:00:00 - 2018-06-02 03:00:00",
     "2018-06-02 07:00:00 - 2018-06-02 06:00:00",
     "2018-06-02 11:00:00 - 2018-06-02 10:00:00",
     "2018-06-02 16:00:00 - 2018-06-02 15:00:00",
     "2018-06-02 22:00:00 - 2018-06-02 21:00:00",
     "2018-06-03 05:00:00 - 2018-06-03 04:00:00",
     "2018-06-03 13:00:00 - 2018-06-03 12:00:00",
     "2018-06-03 22:00:00 - 2018-06-03 21:00:00",
     "2018-06-04 08:00:00 - 2018-06-04 07:00:00",
     "2018-06-04 19:00:00 - 2018-06-04 18:00:00",
     "2018-06-05 07:00:00 - 2018-06-05 06:00:00",
     "2018-06-05 20:00:00 - 2018-06-05 19:00:00",
     "2018-06-06 10:00:00 - 2018-06-06 09:00:00",
     "2018-06-07 01:00:00 - 2018-06-07 00:00:00",
     "2018-06-07 17:00:00 - 2018-06-07 16:00:00",
     "2018-06-08 10:00:00 - 2018-06-08 09:00:00",
     "2018-06-09 04:00:00 - 2018-06-09 03:00:00",
     "2018-06-09 23:00:00 - 2018-06-09 22:00:00",
     "2018-06-10 19:00:00 - 2018-06-10 18:00:00",
     "2018-06-11 16:00:00 - 2018-06-11 15:00:00",
     "2018-06-12 14:00:00 - 2018-06-12 13:00:00",
     "2018-06-13 13:00:00 - 2018-06-13 12:00:00",
   ]
```

It's adding to last `$today` value new `$a` value but when `$a` value is always 1 it is like it never go on last `$today` value but first.

What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks

Comment: So you just want hour and count of users that registered in that hour?

Comment: Yeah for each today's hour

Comment: Maybe something like `select hour(datetimecolumn), count(*) from table group by hour(datetimecolumn)` or you could do `substr` for the first 13(?) characters of the datetimecolumn

Comment: Getting by hours from database aint problem its problem adding one hour 24 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you the results - using SQL only:

```
// Only select users with `created_at` greater than today - start of the day
User::where('created_at', '>', now()->startOfDay())
    // Select created_at hour and count for that hour
    ->selectRaw('date_format(created_at, \'%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00\') as hour, count(users.id) as count')
    // Group by created_at hour
    ->groupBy(\DB::raw('date_format(created_at, \'%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00\')'))
    ->get()
```

Will return something along these lines:

```
[{hour: '2018-06-02 20:00:00', count: 5}, {hour: '2018-06-02 21:00:00', count: 3}, ...]
```

**Edit**

To get all 24 hours I'd do this:

```
// Fetch needed users with 1 query
$users = User::where('created_at', '>', now()->startOfDay())->get();

$result = [];
for ($hour = 0; $hour < 24; $hour++) {
    $result[] = [
        'hour' => $hour,
        'count' => $users->filter(function ($user) use ($hour) {
            // Find users where hour equals to current iteration
            return $user->created_at->hour == $hour;
        })->count(),
    ];
}

return $result;
```

Comment: I dont have problem finding what dates and times someone is registered I need to have all times like 24 hours and like this [{hour: '2018-06-02 00', count: 0},{hour: '2018-06-02 01', count: 1},{hour: '2018-06-02 02', count: 0},] and so on. So I can add it to my chartjs as data.

Comment: Did you try running the query? It groups by an hour, I just added `00:00` to the end to make it more acceptable for most time parsers. If you want it to look like `2018-06-02 00`, just remove the `:00:00` from `'%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00`

Comment: I  did and I got returned only hours when users were registered.

Comment: Ah I see now. Yeah this won't get all 24 hours, only the ones where someone registered. Will fix you up with a solution

Comment: The code I posted worked but carbon adding hours does not work in loop when I try to add 1 hour every time the output for all 24 loops is same. And when I add incrementing hours that needs to be added it works some strange way.
If $a  is always 1 output is like Today with hour 00 + 01 for 24 loop times
If $a is going +1 each time output is Today hour added in loop + incremented $a value.

Comment: Updated my answer, this should get you what you want

Comment: @StupidKid had some errors in previous iteration, now this should work. Tested

Comment: I tested it and it works. The only reason it wouldn't work is if `created_at` isn't cast to a carbon (you'd get an error saying `cant call ->hour on a string` or something like that). Why wouldn't it work?

Comment: When i you your I get output that I got 1 registration at 15 and thats it but I had two at 16:30. I just added $subhour = Carbon::today()->subHour(); and use $today->addHours(1) with $subHour->addHour() and it works as I wanted to :D

Comment: If you had 2 registrations at 16:30, why would they be added to hour 15? They should be added to 16

Comment: Idk always I have some strange problems like that on simple things :D Always. And now I tried and I got 2 on 0 hour but those 2 were yesterday not  today so why are they at 0 :D

Comment: `User::where('created_at', '>', now()->startOfDay())->get();` shouldn't return any users that were created any day other than today. If it does, it seems like your database timezone mismatches your applications timezone. Anyway, glad you solved it

Comment: That could be it I was looking for same thing right now. It was UTC as default but idk. Thanks anyway, wondering why is my question downvoted without explanation :D

Comment: Not sure either. Wasn't me

Comment: Add my answer into your so I can accept it, thanks for losing time on me :D

Comment: Give me an upvote for my efforts and I'll be happy :) I don't want to add your solution, since I don't completely understand it and I don't think you should be doing a separate query for each hour. I'm also pretty confident in my solution

Comment: I'll give you both it's not like I am gonna die :D Thank for your time again! And keep watching my questions 99% of them are not answered :/